# Android : Exchange views between tabs

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost

I actually have an activity called "Creation.java" which provides access to different tabs and that works fine.

My tabs are activities and contains different Views like EditText or Spinners. As I have a lot of datas to save (really a lot) I'd like to propose to the user to fill all the Views by switching between tabs and then, in a last Tab, to validate all the datas and write it in an xml file.

But it seems like I can't get access to the datas from, by example my first tab in order to validate it within the last tab with a validate button.

Example for a customer creation in creationclient.xml which is set in the activity CreationClient.java :

```
        <EditText android:id="@+id/nom1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margexlarge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nom"
            />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/prenom1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margexlarge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prénom"
            />
```

I can't get the content in validation.java, I get an error cause it can't get the String from the View :

```
    nom1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom1);
    prenom1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prenom1);
    validationDuDossier = (Button) findViewById(R.id.validationdudossier);
    idDossier = ((nom1.getText().toString().substring(0, 2)) + (prenom1.getText().toString().substring(0,2)));
```

So my point is : Can I get access to the datas of a layout A in an activity B even if I've set a layout B in this activity ? 
Or do I have an exclusive access to the datas from the layout I set to my activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to link the edit text to the the last tab.
By either doing for example.

```
info.getText().toString(lastTab);
```

or you could do as following

```
lastTab = info.getText().toString();
```

From there you will link the lastTab holding the information to the last Views TextView or how ever you are displaying the information.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, how can you specify an arg for the methode toString() ? So which type is the lastTab ? This method does not take any args.

Comment: You will have to link the information from the first Tab of your activity to the last tab. If you have different classes for each tab you will need to store the information the user enters into a SQLite Database.. If it is in the same class you will need to create variables for one tab and make the information set to the last Tabs data by means of something like this:  LastInfo = FirstInfo.getText().toString; and then user the LastInfo variable to display the information in the last tab.